# FluentNHibernate SubClassMap Issue : Discriminator fail

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a pretty simple problem, but right now can't seem to see the point.
My intention is to read a List of VehicleCollector objects, each one with a neat list of Cars and another list of Trains. Vehicles come from a single table and are discriminated by a column named TYPE.

Model Code:

```
public class VehicleCollector
{
    public virtual IList<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Train> Trains { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle { }

public class Car : Vehicle {}

public class Train : Vehicle { }
```

Mapping Code:

```
public class FooMap : ClassMap<VehicleCollector>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        this.HasMany(x => x.Cars).KeyColumn("foo_id");
        this.HasMany(x => x.Trains).KeyColumn("foo_id");
    }
}

public class VehicleMap : ClassMap<Vehicle>
{
    public VehicleMap() { this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("type"); }
}

public class CarMap : SubclassMap<Car>
{
    public CarMap() { this.DiscriminatorValue(1); }
}

public class TrainMap : SubclassMap<Train>
{
    public TrainMap() { this.DiscriminatorValue(2); }
}
```

I left out IDs and other properties intentionally to keep this readable. It won't compile if you run it the way it is.

What actually happens is that all vehicles are loaded into either one of the collections, so - to my understanding - the discriminator has been neglected.

Do you have any idea what I might be missing / doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** I just ran a SchemaExport to SQLite to see how this behaves. Here's some more detail on what's happening - step by step. Note : Some properties may have changed / been added.

***1) SchemaExport***

```
 create table vehicle_collector
 (
    id INTEGER not null,
   name TEXT not null,
   primary key (id)
);

create table vehicle (
    id INTEGER not null,
   desc TEXT not null,
   type TEXT not null,
   collector_id INTEGER,
   primary key (id)
);
```

***2) Inserting***

```
VehicleCollector c = new VehicleCollector() { Id = 1001, Name = "foobar" };
Train v2 = new Train() { Id = 101, desc = "Foo" };
Car v1 = new Car() { Id = 102, desc = "Bar" };
c.Cars.Add(v1);
c.Trains.Add(v2);
openSession.Save(c);
```

This results in the following SQL (Note that the discriminators are placed as static strings by NHibernate):

```
INSERT INTO vehicle_collector (name, id) VALUES (@p0, @p1); @p0 = 'foobar', @p1 = 1001;
INSERT INTO vehicle (desc, type, id) VALUES ( @p1, '2', @p2); @p1 = 'Foo', @p2 = 101;
INSERT INTO vehicle (desc, type, id) VALUES ( @p1, '1', @p2); @p1 = 'Bar', @p2 = 102;
UPDATE vehicle SET collector_id = @p0 WHERE id = @p1; @p0 = 1001, @p1 = 101;
UPDATE vehicle SET collector_id = @p0 WHERE id = @p1; @p0 = 1001, @p1 = 102;
```

**3) Selecting**

```
VehicleCollector v1 = openSession.CreateCriteria<VehicleCollector>()
                                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", 1001L))
                                    .SetMaxResults(1)
                                    .List<VehicleCollector>()
                                    .First();
Assert.AreEqual(1, v1.Cars.Count);
Assert.AreEqual(1, v1.Trains.Count);
```

This results in the following SQL (Why are there no discriminators here? And what is @p1 in the first select statement generated for?):

```
 SELECT this_.id as id0_0_, this_.name as name0_0_
   FROM vehicle_collector this_
  WHERE this_.id = @p0 limit 1;
 @p0 = 1001, @p1 = 1;

 SELECT vehicle0_.collector_id as collector5_1_,
        vehicle0_.id        as id1_,
        vehicle0_.id        as id1_0_,
        vehicle0_.desc      as desc1_0_
   FROM vehicle vehicle0_
  WHERE vehicle0_.collector_id = @p0;
 @p0 = 1001;
```

Obivously, NHibernate 2.1 has trouble selecting using the discriminator, while inserting works as intended. Any fresh ideas?

TIA

Comment: Tested your configuration (adding ids) - didn't have any problem. Here is my test code: https://gist.github.com/1113933. Wondering whether there is an issue with your add/query methods.

Comment: Hi Richard, I've got something similar working, but once I use a new session for reading the persistent data, the error I described in my original post occurs.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Inserting works fine using the Discriminator...

Comment: I am still unable to produce the error. I was using FNH1.2/NH3.1/MSSQL, so I switched to FNH1.1.0/NH2.1/Sqlite. I am running insert/query in same sqlite session which may be why my asserts work. (However, my original asserts with MSSQL were in a separate session.) Will have to try later in a proper test. Sqlite and FNH are kind of strange bedfellows, especially in test situations. You may want to check out this post: http://www.tigraine.at/2009/05/29/fluent-nhibernate-gotchas-when-testing-with-an-in-memory-database/ (BTW, `@p1` in the query is the `LIMIT 1` - a sqlite idiosyncrasy)

Comment: Hi Richard, the fact that this behaviour can't be reproduced on your machine gives me the willies...docmanhattan had the right idea,so I'm going to check out docs on AlwaysSelectWithValue to understand what it does.

Comment: Thanks again, Richard for taking the time to test this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had something similar (if not the same) where selecting things wasn't working because it wasn't including any of the discriminator information.  To force discriminator information to ALWAYS be included, add this:

```
this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("type").AlwaysSelectWithValue();
```

This will force discriminator information to be included in queries.

Comment: Thanks, Docmanhattan, it works as intended using AlwaysSelectWithValue.

Comment: Where do we have to add this line ?

Comment: @Yowims In the base class mapping (in this case, it is VehicleMap) there is already a call to DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn, you just call the second method afterwards to get the desired behavior.